# Node app.js syntax error: unexpected token

Tags: bots, discord, unexpected-token

I'm new to programming and I wanted to make a discord bot using Atom and Javascript. I had some previous programming experience, but not much. I tried to find help through other Q/A's with the same error code but I still can't figure out why my program doesn't work. I found how to write this online.

My program is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");  
const Config = require("./config.json");  
const Token = require("./token.json");  
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})  
bot.on("ready", async () =>{    
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online! It's running on 
      ${bot.guild.size} servers!`);    
    bot.user.setActivity("Work in Progress", {type: "WATCHING"});  })  
    bot.on("message", async message => {    
       if{message.author.bot} return;    
       if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;    
       message.channel.send("Swift bot testing...")  })  
       bot.login(Token.token);
```

When I tried to run it with node on Windows Powershell by entering "node app.js", it returned with the error message:

```
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token {  at createScript (vm.js:80:10)  at
 Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)  at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)  at Module.load 
(module.js:566:32)  at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)  at 
Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)  at startup 
(bootstrap_node.js:204:16)  at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

I don't understand what is wrong! Somebody please help me get my program running.

Comment: Have you got the solution? if yes, then can you please post it here/

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in if:

```
if{message.author.bot} return;
```

vs

```
if(message.author.bot) return;
```